# Submitting a form via submit event having hidden fields named submit

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have html form which contains one hidden input element that have `name="submit"`:

```
<form method="post" action="url.php">
 <input type="text" name="sometext" />
 <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

I am using this code to submit form:

```
$("#link").click(function() {
 $("form").get(0).submit();
});
```

When I change input name to any other name except `name="submit"` the form is submitted:

```
<form method="post" action="url.php">
 <input type="text" name="sometext" />
 <input type="hidden" name="othername" value="go" />
</form>
<button id="link">Click</button>
<script>
$("#link").click(function() {
 $("form").get(0).submit();
});
</script>
```

The question is Why form is not submitted when hidden input has `name="submit"`?

Comment: There is no element with id `link`: `$("#link")`.

Comment: Do you see any errors here? https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fvnpb6ou/1/

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error you're talking about. It's the difference between telling your doctor that you are in pain and telling him / her where the pain is located :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement):

> Named inputs are added to their owner form instance as properties, and can overwrite native properties if they share the same name (eg a form with an input named action will have its action property return that input instead of the form's action HTML attribute).

Because of that, when you name your button as `submit`, you overwrite the native `submit` function of your form with the button's DOM object. With that your call to `form.submit()` ends up to be equivalent to `form.elements.submit.submit()`, which fails as `form.elements.submit.submit` is actually `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot the name the element *submit*. It is a butoon type inside form. It send all elements of the form to action as you may know. I'd suggest to call your PHP function using that if possible. The *submit()* function is checking for that "submit" button primarily causing issues. If you name something else as "submit", it will be checked for input data.